# Bash Unix | ssh exiting with different user profiles

Tags: java, linux, bash, unix, ssh

I am working in JAVA, trying to implement a com.sshtools.j2ssh.session.SessionChannelClient successfully.  I find my code works great for people who do not have special commands in their profile like /bin/bash.  Like myself, my profile is bash by default, it works great.  Users however, that are native ksh who add /bin/bash to their profile can't use my code.

Here is the heart of my code...

```
    try {
        // Build our connection, and connect
        sessionChannelClient = new SessionChannelClient();
        sshClient = new SshClient();
        sshClient.connect(server, new IgnoreHostKeyVerification());

        // build authentication, and authenticate
        PasswordAuthenticationClient auth = new PasswordAuthenticationClient();
        auth.setUsername(username);
        auth.setPassword(password);
        int authResult = sshClient.authenticate(auth);
        System.out.println("authResult:" +authResult);

        //start working with the session
        sessionChannelClient = sshClient.openSessionChannel();
        SessionOutputReader sor = new SessionOutputReader(sessionChannelClient);
        boolean terminalGood = sessionChannelClient.requestPseudoTerminal("gogrid", 80, 24, 0, 0, "");
        if (!terminalGood){System.out.println("no terminal created..."); return 99;}

        if (sessionChannelClient.startShell()) {

            //build an in/out so we can see the text to and from unix
            ChannelInputStream channelInputStream = sessionChannelClient.getInputStream();
            ChannelOutputStream channelOutputStream = sessionChannelClient.getOutputStream();
            //System.out.println(in);

            // RUN THE COMMAND
            System.out.println("Sending command to UNIX.....");
            channelOutputStream.write(command.getBytes());
            Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);//unix needs time to run the commands

            System.out.println("ScriptName | " + script);
            System.out.println("providePassword flag|" + providePassword);
            if( script.equals("propSync.shl")|| script.equals("nonsrcSync.shl")){providePassword = false;}

            //The java app called by the script needs a password
            if (providePassword) {
                channelOutputStream.write(tempPassword.getBytes());
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 3);//unix needs time to run the commands
            }
            else{ System.out.println("providePassword not required it seems for -->" + script); }

            // Close the channel
            String exit = "exit\n";
            while(sessionChannelClient.getState().getValue() != ChannelState.CHANNEL_CLOSED){
                System.out.println("lets try to exit the sessionChannelClient...." + sessionChannelClient.getState().getValue());
                channelOutputStream.write(exit.getBytes()); // without this, it wont log out correctly
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);//unix needs time to run the commands
            }
            exitCode = sessionChannelClient.getExitCode();
            System.out.println("just outside of while loop SessionState:" + sessionChannelClient.getState().getValue());
            System.out.println("just outside of while loop EXITCODE:" + exitCode);
            sessionChannelClient.close();
        } 
        else { System.out.println("the shell refused to start"); return 99;}
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { printOUtMessages(e, "Exception", script, server, command); return 99;} 
    finally { sshClient.disconnect(); }

    //Wrap up and return back
    calculateTime(startTime, exitCode, baseMessage);
    return exitCode; // non-zero means failure
```

Comment: If they are adding /bin/bash to thier .profile instead of having their default shell updated they are doing it wrong. Not that that makes your problem any less real, dealing with that sort of stuff is part of the job, but I just thought that should be said.

Comment: 1) Can you explain why it doesn't work. 2) Users should be switching shell by running `chsh`

Comment: For those of us with standard bash profiles it works perfect, notice the little while loop I added.

Comment: For those of us with standard bash profiles it works perfect, notice the little while loop I added.  For me for example, it will loop three times, and exit with a return code of 1 ( which is what I want )telling the user that the subversion merge failed.

For users who have /bin/bash in the .profile, it loops more times, and ALWAYS returns 0;  In this case we are trying to do a subversion merge, and this is falsely telling the user that the merge was successful.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack - Solaris has bash but not chsh by default, true on some other non-Linux boxes - the OP has UNIX as a tag, so this is relevant